# How to build a shared object (.so) with missing dependencies

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, .so

I would like to build a shared object (let's name it A) that depends on another .so (let's name it B). B is implementing some interface that A is using.

The machine that will load A also has B so when loading A (at load time or via dlopen), it loads B and everything is fine.
The issue is that I cannot build B (on the machine I am building A) and therefore cannot build A, since I get a linker error.
of course I expect to see B as dependency when doing 'ldd A'.

Is there a linker option to build A without having B?

[a picture to visualize my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjs8i.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that I cannot build B (on the machine I am building A) and therefore cannot build A, since I get a linker error.

There is a lot of missing info here.

1. You have a version of `B.so` *somewhere*. Why can't you copy that version onto the machine on which you are building `A.so`, and use it to actually build `A.so` ?
2. With default linker flags, you *should* be able to link `A.so` even though it uses symbols from `B.so` *without* having `B.so` available (unresolved symbols are ignored by default when building with `-shared`).
   This will produce `A.so` which *doesn't* depend on `B.so`. At `dlopen()` time you will simply have to load `B.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL` before loading `A.so`.
3. If you really need to have the `A.so -> B.so` dependency, you can create an *empty* `B.so` and link against *that*.