# How to build a dynamic library with no dynamic dependencies?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I want to build a shared object, that I can load using LD_PRELOAD (which replaces some functionality of otherwise loaded libraries).
How can I make this library to have no dynamic dependencies (i.e. essentially being a static build of a shared library, if that makes sense)?

Something simple like `gcc -shared -static -fPIC source.c` fails.
I skimmed through the other related questions, and cannot seem to find something that would work in this scenario.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a shared object (.so) with missing dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511841/how-to-build-a-shared-object-so-with-missing-dependencies)

Comment: This is a similar situation, but, following the linked question, I have A and B, my target possibly also uses some B', but I want to make sure I use my B. Also I will not have B on the target (and providing it would require a lot of work)

Comment: are you familiar with "partial linking"? That seems to be what you are describing

Comment: Thanks for that hint, though I suppose this would require me to rebuild the libraries my target requires, right? (instead of LD_PRELOAD). This could solve the problem, I guess, but this is very annoying, I would rather just preload when needed